# android-can't use adapter with recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm getting data json data from web , This is my code for setting adapter to my recycleView :

```
    RecyclerView recycle;
    MyAdapter adapters;
    private static String url;
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    JSONArray contacts = null;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private int preLast;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        url = "http://192.168.1.20/adres/getAds.php";

        recycle=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycle);
        recycle.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

 private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
        Boolean goterr=false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Spots_tab1_json sh = new Spots_tab1_json();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, Spots_tab1_json.GET);
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataC = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
                    if(contacts.length()<20)
                        loadmore=false;

                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        contact.put("id", new String(c.getString("id").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
                        contact.put("url", new String(c.getString("url").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
                        contact.put("text", new String(c.getString("text").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));                       dataC.add(contact);
                        dataC.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.v("this", e.getMessage());
                    goterr=true;
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    Log.v("this",e.getMessage());
                    goterr=true;
                }
            } else {
                goterr=true;
            }
            return dataC;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing() && pDialog != null)
                pDialog.dismiss();

            if(!isCancelled() && goterr==false && result!=null){
                if(adapters==null){
                    adapters=new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,result);
                    recycle.setAdapter(adapters);
                }else{
                    MyAdapter.addAll(result);
                }
            }else{
                //MyToast.makeText(MainActivity.this, DariGlyphUtils.reshapeText(MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.problemload)));
            }

        }
    }


    public class Information {
        String thumbnail;
        String title ;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getThumbnail() {
            return thumbnail;
        }

        public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
            this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        }
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>list){
            inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.list=list;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parrent, int i) {
            View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.customrow,parrent,false);
            MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }

        public void addAll(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            if(this.list==null){
                this.list =result;
            }else{
                this.list.addAll(result);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            Information current=list.get(position);
            viewHolder.txt.setText(current.title);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView txt ;
            ImageView img ;
            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                txt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
                img= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            }
        }
    }
```

There are 2 parts of code that I have problem with :
1- in the onPostExecute , this line :

```
MyAdapter.addAll(result);
```

The error is :non static method 'addAll(java.util.ArrayList>)' cannot be referenced from a static context

The second error is on the adapter ,onBindViewHolder method, this line :

```
Information current=list.get(position);
```

it says:
incompatible types .
Required .com.example.navid.MainActivity.Information
Found :java.util.hashmap

What am I doing is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aren't you supposed to the following ?

```
adapters.addAll instead of MyAdapter.addAll
```

you adapter has the list data as following.

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;
```

so when you are trying to do

```
list.get(position);
```

it will return element of type HashMap. But you are trying to assign this to element of type Information.